# How can I properly turn string to list of words and punctuation marks?

Tags: c#, string

I have string: `IDLIST, ID NAME;`. And need to turn it into list: `{"IDLIST", ",", "ID", "NAME", ";"}`.

It's obvious how to slice string by free spaces, but what to do with punctuation marks?

Words can be any set of letters. Punctuation marks also can be any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `Regex.Split` function like below,

```
string value = "IDLIST, ID NAME;";
string[] lines = Regex.Split(value, @"\s+|(?!^)(?=\p{P})|(?<=\p{P})(?!$)");
foreach (string line in lines) {
Console.WriteLine(line);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/8Z1KiA)

**OR**

You could match all the punctuations or the alphabets  and then append the matched strings to a list.

```
@"\p{P}|\p{L}+"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zB3hI5/16)

`\p{P}` matches any kind of punctuation marks and `p{L}` matches any kind of letter from any language.